# Would appreciate some tips on designing simple OpAmp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, input-impedance

I've recently posted [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/617170/opamp-input-impedance-when-working-with-dc-signal) regarding input impedance when working with DC signal on [HCPL-7840 Isolation Amplifier](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-1289EN). The answers were very clarifying and helpful, but I've come to realize I need more specific help.

Just a disclaimer: I decided to use HCPL-7840 because it was the best option available on my chosen supplier that seems to fufil my needs.

##### My goal is to design a simple isolated amplifier for an NTC

---

- NTC characteristics considered:

  | Resistance [kΩ] | Temperature [ºC] |
  | --- | --- |
  | 10 | 30 |
  | 15 | 20 |
  | 20 | 10 |
  | 25 | 0 |
- HCPL-7840 characteristics considered:

  - The information on the "Recommended Operating Conditions" table of datasheet
  - Equivalent Input Impedance RIN — 500 — kΩ
  - Figures 12 and 14 of datasheet

---

- Based on these informations, I designed the following simple circuit:

  - It's composed of a simple voltage divider, where `R1` is fixed precise resistor, and `R2` is the NTC.

[image]

- As soon as I assembled the board and started making measurements, I noticed that the voltages on TP1 were not exactly what I expected to see

  - I was expecting a simple voltage divider between `R1`, `R2`
  - I figured the difference should be because of internal resistence of HCPL (`Rin`), between pins 2 and 3
  - This `Rin` is suposelly connected in parallel with `R2` (between TP1 and GND iso)
- I than started to conduct some experiments to empirically try and figure out the value of `Rin`. This way I could calculate adjusted values for `R1` and `R2` and keep the voltage on TP1 within the input limits of HCPL linear range

  - The experiment consists of trying different combinations of `R1` and `R2` and measuring the voltage at `TP1`.
  - **The results of this experiments drive me crazy** because different combinations of `R1`, `R2` make me infer different values for `Rin` each time.
  - The following table summarizes the experiment results:

    | Index | Vdd [V] | R1 [Ω] | R2 [Ω] | V measured @ TP1 [V] |
    | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
    | 1 | 5.40 | 2150 | 100 | 0.213 |
    | 2 | 5.45 | 2150 | 68 | 0.158 |
    | 3 | 5.56 | 2150 | 40 | 0.101 |
    | 4 | 5.55 | 246000 | 11600 | 0.186 |
    | 5 | 5.70 | 246000 | 5800 | 0.119 |
    | 6 | 5.77 | 717500 | 11600 | 0.082 |
    | 7 | 5.79 | 717500 | 23500 | 0.113 |
    | 8 | 5.84 | 717500 | 51300 | 0.142 |
  - `Vdd` and `V measured @ TP1` were measured with osciloscope.
  - `R1` and `R2` were measured with Ohmmeter before the experiment.
  - Outcomes:

    - Given `Vdd`, `R1` and `V measured @ TP1`, I was able to calculate what would be the "real `R2`" that the circuit is submited to.
    - This "real `R2`" would be the parallel between `R2` (from the table) and `Rin`
    - Because I have `R2`, I'm able to calculate `Rin`
  - **After this procedure I ended up with a lot of different values of `Rin` for each experiment case, and I don't know how to proceed!!!**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: transferring an analog signal over an opto is challenging. You'l get much better linearity using the opto to transfer a frequency or pulse width. You could probably use a NE555 in both of those cases. Assuming you go with a pulse width modulated signal, analog filtering on the output of the opto will create an analog signal. Of course, you could use a single chip micro and just transmit uart data across the opto. Or go Bluetooth or WiFi and negate the need for an opto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figure 14 of the datasheet suggests that the input current into the HCPL-7840 should be fairly linear (resistor like) for input voltages in the range of -200mV to +200mV.  But acconding to note 12 on page 18 of the datasheet the input stage is actually a "switched capacitor", not a real resistor, so there is going to be current spikes.  I would suggest putting a 0.1uF ceramic capacitor across R2.

I would also suggest making changes that make your circuit less sensitive to input current on the HCPL-7840 input pins.

- One option is to buffer the + input of the HCPL-7840 with another rail-to-rail op-amp configured as a voltage follower.
- Alternatively, you could lower the values of R1 and R2 enough that the input current into the HCPL-7840 doesn't affect the measurement as much.

Answer (score 2):

from datasheet ...

> Description
> The Broadcom® HCPL-7840 isolation amplifier family is
> designed for current sensing in electronic motor drives. In a
> typical implementation, motor currents flow through an
> external resistor and the resulting analog voltage drop is
> sensed by the HCPL-7840. A **differential output voltage is
> created on the other side** of the HCPL-7840 optical isolation
> barrier. This differential output voltage is proportional to the
> motor current and can be converted to a single-ended signal
> by using an op-amp as shown in the recommended
> application circuit.

You need using it as a "**differential**" device. Not single input(ok)/output(not ok).
So you need using something as figure 4 in the datasheet.